# Displaying push notifications in angular

Tags: angular, angular7, web-push

App.ts

```js
const VAPID_PUBLIC = "XXX"

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'web';

  constructor(swPush: SwPush, pushService: PushNotificationService) {
    if (swPush.isEnabled) {
      swPush
        .requestSubscription({
          serverPublicKey: VAPID_PUBLIC,
        })
        .then(subscription => {
          pushService.sendSubscriptionToTheServer(subscription).subscribe(change => {

          })
        })
        .catch(console.error)
    }
  }
```

push-notification.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

const SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/subscription'

@Injectable()
export class PushNotificationService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public sendSubscriptionToTheServer(subscription: PushSubscription) {
    return this.http.post(SERVER_URL, subscription)
  }
}
```

server.js

```javascript
const express = require('express');
const webpush = require('web-push');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const PUBLIC_VAPID =
  'XXX';
const PRIVATE_VAPID = 'XXX';

const fakeDatabase = [];

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

webpush.setVapidDetails('mailto:domain@test.com', PUBLIC_VAPID, PRIVATE_VAPID);

app.post('/subscription', (req, res) => {
  const subscription = req.body;
  fakeDatabase.push(subscription);
});

app.post('/sendNotification', (req, res) => {
  const notificationPayload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'New Notification',
      body: 'This is the body of the notification',
    },
  };

  const promises = [];
  fakeDatabase.forEach(subscription => {
    promises.push(
      webpush.sendNotification(
        subscription,
        JSON.stringify(notificationPayload)
      )
    );
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then(() => res.sendStatus(200));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

- With the above code, I'm trying to display notifications using angular and express. I started the server on `http://localhost:3000` then ran `ng build --prod` `then http-server dist/apps/projectName`.
- The request for notifications is working whether to allow or not, on clicking allow, I get response 200 in (checking in network tab chrome dev tools). But the notification message is not getting popped up or displayed in the browser. I need help in fixing this.

I tried the code from https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-push-notifications/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to add a popup message:

```
pushService.sendSubscriptionToTheServer(subscription).subscribe(change => {

    //-->Here you need to write popup message after notification

})
```

Comment: Thank you, is there any syntax for that?

Comment: As such there is no syntax but you may use alert or customized way of showing message box.